# Dynamically create v-model from form input field in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

I want to create a form dynamically from a json response obtained from backend.
Here is the code:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div v-for="field in form">
            <div v-if="field.type === 'text'">
                <input type="text" :name="field.name" :placeholder="field.label"/>
            </div>
            <div v-else-if="field.type === 'radio'">
                <div v-for="option in field.options">
                    <label>
                        <input type="radio" :name="field.name" :value="option">
                        <span class="text">{{ option }}</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                form: [
                    {
                        name: 'first_name',
                        label: 'First Name',
                        type: 'text',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'last_name',
                        label: 'Last Name',
                        type: 'text',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'gender',
                        label: 'Gender',
                        type: 'radio',
                        options: ['male','female'],
                    }
                ],
                response: [], <!--I want to populate this array with form response.-->
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Now, I don't know how many fields to be created and don't know the name. I get a different response from each different request. So I need a way to fill the `response[]` array with form data. The `response[]` array may look like this:

```
      response: [
                    {
                        name: 'first_name',
                        value: 'Yeasir',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'last_name',
                        value: 'Arafat',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'gender',
                        value: 'male',
                    }
                ]
```

How can I achieve the result? It would be a great help.

Comment: Can you explain the problem a little bit more, Not understanding your requirement here

Comment: @theFrontEndDev I want to grab all the input fields of a form and save the name and value of the fields in an array variable named `response[]`. It is like `v-bind` but it has to be dynamic because I can not what the form contains.